# Intellij IDEA Node.js typescript debugger not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Node.js project which uses typescript. I start the project using the following command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./handle-uploaded-image/app.ts
```

This works flawlessly. Whenever I try to start the project in debug mode via Intellij IDEA I get the following error:

```
./handle-uploaded-image/node_modules/.bin/ts-node 
./handle-uploaded-image/app.ts
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61933/6d785785-a696-44da-8256-9123895981ed
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
env: node: No such file or directory
Error in JetBrains node debug connector:  Error: Command failed: 
./handle-uploaded-image/node_modules/.bin/ts-node 
/private/var/folders/y4/b5h5p9wj471d3zzz_vn8t8dw0000gn/T/debugConnector.201.7223.91.js
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
    at Object.<anonymous>             
(/private/var/folders/y4/b5h5p9wj471d3zzz_vn8t8dw0000gn/T/debugConnector.201.7223.91.js:30:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1345:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:439:5) {
  status: 127,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 25469,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

The project runs but breakpoints are ignored so the debugger doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: looks as if `node` is not on your `$PATH`; what OS are you on? does the issue persist if you start IDEA from terminal? Note that using `ts-node` as Node.js interpreter is not supported. You have to specify a valid path to node.js instead, passing `--require ts-node/register` as a *Node parameter*

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've already solved it by using node --require ts-node/register instead of ts-node . The debugger works well now.